# java:implement 8 queen using depth first search

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, n-queens

i am try to implement 8 queen using depth search for any initial state it work fine for empty board(no queen on the board) ,but i need it to work for initial state if there is a solution,if there is no solution for this initial state it will print there is no solution

Here is my code:

```
public class depth {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //we create a board
       int[][] board = new int[8][8];
       board [0][0]=1;
       board [1][1]=1;
       board [2][2]=1;
       board [3][3]=1;
       board [4][4]=1;
       board [5][5]=1;
       board [6][6]=1;
       board [7][7]=1;

       eightQueen(8, board, 0, 0, false);
       System.out.println("the solution as pair");
       for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<board.length;j++)
               if(board[i][j]!=0)

               System.out.println("  ("+i+" ,"+j +")");
       }
       System.out.println("the number of node stored in memory "+count1);
   }
      public static int count1=0;
     public static void eightQueen(int N, int[][] board, int i, int j, boolean found) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();//time start

    if (!found) {
        if (IsValid(board, i, j)) {//check if the position is valid
            board[i][j] = 1;

            System.out.println("[Queen added at (" + i + "," + j + ")");
            count1++;
            PrintBoard(board);


            if (i == N - 1) {//check if its the last queen
                found = true;
                PrintBoard(board);
                double endTime = System.nanoTime();//end the method time

                double duration = (endTime - startTime)*Math.pow(10.0, -9.0);
                System.out.print("total Time"+"= "+duration+"\n");
            }
            //call the next step
            eightQueen(N, board, i + 1, 0, found);
        } else {

            //if the position is not valid & if reach the last row we backtracking
            while (j >= N - 1) {
                int[] a = Backmethod(board, i, j);
                i = a[0];
                j = a[1];

                System.out.println("back at (" + i + "," + j + ")");
                PrintBoard(board);
            }
            //we do the next call
            eightQueen(N, board, i, j + 1, false);
        }
    }

}

public static int[] Backmethod(int[][] board, int i, int j) {
    int[] a = new int[2];
    for (int x = i; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (int y = j; y >= 0; y--) {
            //search for the last queen
            if (board[x][y] != 0) {
                //deletes the last queen and returns the position
                board[x][y] = 0;
                a[0] = x;
                a[1] = y;
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}

public static boolean IsValid(int[][] board, int i, int j) {

    int x;
    //check the queens in column
    for (x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
        if (board[i][x] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check the queens in row
    for (x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
        if (board[x][j] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check the queens in the diagonals
    if (!SafeDiag(board, i, j)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean SafeDiag(int[][] board, int i, int j) {

    int xx = i;
    int yy = j;
    while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
        if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        yy++;
        xx++;
    }
    xx = i;
    yy = j;
    while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
        if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        yy--;
        xx--;
    }
    xx = i;
    yy = j;
    while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
        if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        yy--;
        xx++;
    }
    xx = i;
    yy = j;
    while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
        if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        yy++;
        xx--;
    }
    return true;
}
public static void PrintBoard(int[][] board) {
    System.out.print(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Q");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}


}
```

for example for this initial state it give me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

i am stuck, i think the error is infinite call for the method how to solve this problem.

any idea will be helpful,thanks in advance.

note:the broad is two dimensional array,when i put (1) it means there queen at this point.

note2:
we i put the initial state as the following it work:

```
       board [0][0]=1;
       board [1][1]=1;
       board [2][2]=1;
       board [3][3]=1;
       board [4][4]=1;
       board [5][5]=1;
       board [6][6]=1;
       board [7][1]=1;
```

Comment: What have you done so far to analyze the problem? Have you tried adding printouts to watch what it's working on, or running it in a debugger, or reporting the search depth (it shouldn't have to go past the number of cells on the board, right?), or...

Comment: @keshlam i try,but i can not figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT: Added conditional output tip.]

To add to @StephenC's answer:

This is a heck of a complicated piece of code, especially if you're not experienced in programming Java.

I executed your code, and it outputs this over and over and over and over (and over)

```
back at (0,0)
 01234567
0
1 Q
2  Q
3   Q
4    Q
5     Q
6      Q
7       Q
back at (0,0)
```

And then crashes with this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    at Depth.eightQueen(Depth.java:56)
    at Depth.eightQueen(Depth.java:60)
    at Depth.eightQueen(Depth.java:60)
    at Depth.eightQueen(Depth.java:60)
    at Depth.eightQueen(Depth.java:60)
    ...
```

My first instinct is always to add some `System.out.println(...)`s to figure out where stuff is going wrong, but that won't work here.

The only two options I see are to

- Get familiar with a debugger and use it to step through and analyze why it's never stopping the loop
- Break it down man! How can you hope to deal with a massive problem like this without breaking it into digestible chunks???

Not to mention that the concept of [8-queens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) is complicated to begin with.

---

One further thought:

`System.out.println()`s are not useful as currently implemented, because there's infinite output. A debugger is the better solution here, but another option is to somehow limit your output. For example, create a counter at the top

```
private static final int iITERATIONS = 0;
```

and instead of

```
System.out.println("[ANUMBERFORTRACING]: ... USEFUL INFORMATION ...")
```

use

```
conditionalSDO((iITERATIONS < 5), "[ANUMBERFORTRACING]: ... USEFUL INFORMATION");
```

Here is the function:

```
private static final void conditionalSDO(boolean b_condition, String s_message)  {
   if(b_condition)  {
       System.out.println(s_message);
   }
}
```

Another alternative is to not limit the output, but to [write it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15754658/2736496).

I hope this information helps you.

(Note: I edited the OP's code to be compilable.)

Comment: The strange board position comes from `main` I think.  (I cannot comprehend why the OP initializes the board to an obviously incorrect solution ...).  FWIW, it should possible to code a solution in ~50 lines of Java; e.g. see the Wikipedia sample solution.

Comment: @aliteralmind i use System.out.println(...)s to figure out where stuff is going wrong,but i can where is the error?

Comment: @aliteralmind thanks for reply,but can you help me out.

Comment: Just added the answer above. Take another look.

Comment: @aliteralmind i know where is the error but i do not know how to fix it,please help.

Comment: If you know exactly where the error is now, I recommend you post another question about it, with as much specific information as you can, including the full stack trace. Please post code that people can just copy, paste, compile, and run, without having to change anything. Try to reduce your problem as much as possible. The more you can do to help us, the more we can do to help you. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Actually, when you figure everything out, consider posting your working code, and what you figured out. Don't change the original question or code! Just add to the bottom.

Comment: Counters probably shouldn't be static and definitely shouldn't be final

Answer (score 2):

You asked for ideas on **how to** solve it (as distinct from solutions!) so, here's a couple of hints:

Hint #1:

If you get a `StackOverflowError` in a recursive program it can mean one of two things:

- your problem is too "deep", OR
- you've got a bug in your code that is causing it to recurse *infinitely*.

In this case, the depth of the problem is small (8), so this must be a recursion bug.

Hint #2:

If you examine the stack trace, you will see the method names and line numbers for each of the calls in the stack.  This ... and some thought ... should help you figure out the pattern of recursion in your code (as implemented!).

Hint #3:

Use a debugger Luke ...

Hint #4:

If you want other people to read your code, pay more attention to style.  Your indentation is messed up in the most important method, and you have committed the (IMO) unforgivable sin of ignoring the Java style rules for identifiers.  A method name MUST start with a lowercase letter, and a class name MUST start with an uppercase letter.

(I stopped reading your code very quickly ... on principle.)

Comment: i spend a lot of hours trying to solve it but i am stuck,please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter your method `IsValid` in the lines where  `for (x = 0; x < board.length - 1; x++)`.

```
public static boolean IsValid(int[][] board, int i, int j) {
    int x;
    //check the queens in column
    for (x = 0; x < board.length - 1; x++) {
        if (board[i][x] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check the queens in row
    for (x = 0; x < board.length - 1; x++) {
        if (board[x][j] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check the queens in the diagonals
    if (!SafeDiag(board, i, j)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```