# writeDouble() method of DataOutputStream is writing data in text document in encoded form

Tags: java, dataoutputstream

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String aed[]){
    double d=17.3;
    try{
            DataOutputStream out=null;
            out=new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("new.txt")));
            out.writeDouble(d);
            out.flush();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Now I am writing this double value to a text file new.txt , but following value is getting in text file

```
@1LÌÌÌÌÍ
```

But when i use

```
out.writeUTF(""+d)
```

It works fine.
Please explain the encoding that is going on here.

Comment: what is d here? Where is it initialized?

Comment: That was a typing error, apologies.

Comment: There is no encoding. A `DataOutputStream` is a binary stream, despite the fact that you called the file *something.txt*. If you hex-dump the file, you'll see that the `writeUTF` writes some non-text bytes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DataOutputStream` you are writing bytes, the bytes that represent a double value (which is a number value) and not the readable version of that number.

Example:

int i = 8;

In binary i value is '0100' and that's the value that the computer manages.... But you don't want to write the bits '0100' because you want something to read, not it's value; you want the CHARACTER '8', so you must transform the double to character (to String is also valid because is readable)....

And that's what you are doing with ("" + d): transforming it to String.

Use Writer to write text files (BufferedWriter and FileWriter are available, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754523/how-to-write-text-file-java) for more details)

Answer (score 1):

In java there are generally two classes of variables namely reference and primitive types.

Your primitive types include int,double,byte,char,boolean,long,short and float. These store one value and are represented in memory by a unicode 16 bit integer.

Reference types hold storage locations and referneces to certain objects. ( string/UTF is a refernce type) hence the actual value is seen

A binary file is not meant to be read by you but by a program that will fetch the values in the correct form and order and the methods you are using should be used solely for writing to a binary file(.dat) which holds actual data values in their respective forms (int,double etc). When writing to a textfile (.txt) text should be written only hence strings.

Writing to a Textfile :

```
try{
PrintWriter write=new PrintWriter("your filepath",true);
write.println("whatever needs to be written");

write.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException){
}
```

Reading :

```
Scanner read;
try{
read=new Scanner(new FileReader("your path"));


while(read.hasNext()){
System.out.println(read.nextLine);
}

read.close();
}

catch(FileNotFoundException e){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.DataOuputStream.writeUTF(String str)` Writes two bytes of length information to the output stream, followed by the modified **UTF-8** representation of every character in the string s.

```
writeDouble(double v)
```

> Converts the double argument to a long using the doubleToLongBits
>   method in class Double, and then writes that long value to the
>   underlying output stream as an 8-byte quantity, high byte first.

Read the Javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

```
writeDouble(Double)
```

method does not use UTF-8 encoding. If you have written a double using `writeDoble()` then you should read it using `readDouble` method of `DataInputStream`. These files are not meant to be modified or read manually. If you want to put it in plain then stick to `writeUTF` method.

From Documentation -

```
writeDouble  -
```

Converts the double argument to a long using the doubleToLongBits method in class Double, and then writes that long value to the underlying output stream as an 8-byte quantity, high byte first.

Answer (score 0):

`writeDouble` (as another `writeByte`, `writeShort`, etc. with corresponding size of bytes) writes 8 bytes of double value representation. That's why class called as `DataOutputStream` (**Data**).

`writeUTF` writes 2 bytes of length and actual string.