# How to write ArrayList data to text file in java

Tags: java, arraylist, printwriter

I m trying to write ArrayList data in to the Text file using this code:

```
 public PrintWriter w() {
        try {
            FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\jon\\Desktop\\a.txt");
            PrintWriter br = new PrintWriter(f);

            return br;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

        return null;
    }

for (String g : a) {
  try {
    PrintWriter br = w();
    br.println(g);
    System.out.print(" " + g);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
  }
```

But it is not writing the data to the text file. Can anyone help me see the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Write text file Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754523/how-to-write-text-file-java)

Comment: You can convert it to JSON and then write it to text file.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)

Comment: @SachinMesare how to Convert plz explain.

Comment: You can use any library like Gson or Jackson to convert arraylist to Json

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Can you share those? Make sure to `close()` the `PrintWriter` when you are finished. You also need to open the `PrintWriter` outside of the loop, so that previous text isn't overwritten with each new `PrintWriter`.

Comment: @Jon look at the answer using FileWriter.. it has worked.. have tested it

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
public static BufferedWriter w() throws IOException{
         File file = new File("D:\\filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        return bw;

        }
```

and this is what you need to call from your for loop:

```
for (String g : a) {
    try {

            BufferedWriter bw = w();

            bw.write(g);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```